# Is there any way to change the color of the label on a Plot.ly JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, plotly

On the graph in the JSBin link below, which is generated with Plotly (https://plot.ly/javascript/), when you hover over the bar chart 'bars', the values associated with each bar are displayed - however the text color corresponds to the color the bar is set to and is unreadable if a light color.

https://jsbin.com/vubahafasu/edit?html,js,output

So essentially, when hover of the Giraffes Bar items, is it possible to change the color or bgcolor of the hover values of "SF Zoo" that is displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [plotly_hover](https://plot.ly/javascript/hover-events/) event, select the `rect` which shows the text and change its fill color.
The class of the `rect` is `hovertext` and by using D3's [filter](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_filter) method you can select the index for which the modification is applied.

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").on("plotly_hover", function (data) {
data.points.map(function () {
    var hovertext = Plotly.d3.selectAll(".hovertext");
    hovertext.filter(function (d, i) {
        return i === 0;
    }).selectAll("rect").style("fill", "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
});
```

});

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'], 
  y: [20, 14, 23], 
  name: 'SF Zoo', 
  type: 'bar',
  marker: {
    color: '#e9e9e9'
  }
};

var trace2 = {
  x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'], 
  y: [12, 18, 29], 
  name: 'LA Zoo', 
  type: 'bar'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

var layout = {barmode: 'group'};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);

document.getElementById('myDiv').on('plotly_hover', function(data){
    var infotext = data.points.map(function(d){
    var hovertext = Plotly.d3.selectAll(".hovertext");
    hovertext.filter(function(d, i) {return i === 0; }).selectAll('rect').style("fill" , "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myDiv" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Perfect - works like a charm:
https://jsbin.com/pedaki/edit?html,js,output

Comment: How would I implement this in angular? I am using the <plotly> tag to generate the UIs